# is there a way to add new feature to orientdb studio

Tags: orientdb

is there a way i can add a new feature to the orientdb studio? I mean, I need to display a popup window with a timeline of events that each user has made in a frame of time, for now when we click on a node a set of features appeared to modify, see connections to the vertex and connection from the vertex. SO can I add a feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a feature request on [github](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues).